# Could hall encoders that are attached to the DC motors affect each other or the IMUs?

Tags: encoder, imu, mobile-robot, rotary-encoder

I am a newbie and I want to build an autonomous mobile robot. I am planning to use 4 DC motors with hall-effect encoders. I will use 4 IMUs for localization at first. Next, I also have the plan to combine encoder data and IMUs data for localization. Then, include GPS also for localization.

I want to know considering the distance between the encoders and IMUs in the attached figure, could the performance of the encoders and IMUs be affected by each other?

[image]

Comment: Do the IMUs rely on magnetism? Refer to their datasheet for guidance. Also note that the hall effect sensors detect magnetism, not generate it, so there is no interaction between the hall sensors and your IMUs. It is the motor that generates the magnetism.

Comment: Thank you for the information that the hall encoders won't affect each other as they do not generate any magnetism. I am using Adafruit BNO055 IMU. The BNO055 has a triaxial geomagnetic sensor.

Comment: It’s not an IMU (inertial measurement unit) if it uses  a magnetometer!  Yes, you will need to be careful where you place these sensors in relation to the motor, relays and wiring carrying significant current. The simplest way to determine if you are getting positioning errors due to stray magnetism is to start/stop the motor and observe the output of your sensor.